# ng-model bloqueado al llenarlo de manera dinámico

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directivas, angularjs-scope

Tengo un formulario en el cual tengo unos input text que se crean según los productos que obtenga, el caso es que quiero mostrar en esos input unos valores por defecto pero al asignarle el valor al ng-model los input me quedan bloqueados y no me deja editarlos.

```
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="producto in productoss" ng-if="producto.producto_categoria_id == categoria.id_producto_categoria">
      <div class="col" ng-show="!comision_compra">
        <label class="item item-input">
          {{ productoData[producto.id_producto] = productos_interlocutor[producto.id_producto] * 100;""}}
          <input type="text" ng-model="productoData[producto.id_producto]" value="{{ productoData[producto.id_producto] }}" ng-readonly="false" >
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col" ng-show="!comision_compra">
        {{comisiones_punto_venta[producto.id_producto] * 100}}
      </div>

    </div>
```

Este es el formulario en el cual requiero la ayuda y este es el controlador

```
Transacciones.getAllProductsComercio()
    .success(function(response) {

      // Asigna los productos y las categorias al scope para ser mostrados en el template.
      $scope.productoss              = response.detail.productos;
      $scope.categoriass             = response.detail.categorias;


    }).error(function(response, status){

        // Muestra un mensaje de error al usuario.
        var msg = response.detail || 'Ocurrió un error al obtener los productos.';
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Error.',
          template: msg
        });

        // Oculta el mensaje de carga.
        $ionicLoading.hide();

        // Notfica que hubo un error al obtener los prodcutos.
        $scope.errorObteniendoProductos = true;
    });


Transacciones.getInfoProductos($scope.comercio)
    .success(function(response) {

      $scope.productos_interlocutor = response.detail.productos_interlocutor;
      $scope.comisiones_punto_venta = response.detail.comisiones_punto_venta;
      $scope.interlocutor           = response.detail.interlocutor;

      if ($scope.interlocutor.tipo_comision === 'C') {
        $scope.comision_compra = true;
      }




    }).error(function(response, status){


    });
```

Les agradezco su colaboración

Comment: Si quieres que le presten atencion a tu pregunta tienes que reducir la cantidad de codigo. Solo deja lo relevante para que se haga mas facil encontrar el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia, ya lo edite y le baje la cantidad de código

Comment: a modo de que sepas si colocas una variable en el ng-model `<input ng-model="productoData[producto.id_producto]">` automaticamente te imprimira el valor guardado si no tiene lo dejara en blanco, solo debes actualizar el valor `productoData[producto.id_producto]`si lo haces desde el contoller sera algo como `$scope.productoData[producto.id_producto]`

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es dificil ayudar con un codigo tan dificil de leer pero voy a hacer un esfuerzo.

1. Asumo que en algun lugar tienes definido   `$scope.productoData = [];`
2. Asumo que  `$scope.productoss   !=  $scope.productoData.`

Por ultimo solo necesita definir la variable que desea leer con ng-model. Por lo tanto use

```
<input type="text" ng-model="productoData[producto.id_producto]">
```

en sustitucion de:

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="productoData[producto.id_producto]" value="{{ productoData[producto.id_producto] }}" ng-readonly="false" >
```

Note: value = {{ productoData[producto.id_producto] }} representa 1 way binding por lo tanto el valor no va a poder ser modificado.

Espero le sea util la respuesta, Y por favor recuerde que la idea de AngularJS, Angular, React, Vue es hacer el codigo lo mas simple posible.

Gracias!!!